# how to change the text color of file chosen in asp:fileUpload in Safari?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, safari

I have made web application using C# and used `asp:fileUpload` for that.

But when I published it and run in Safari in MAC, it shows chosen file name for upload in black color which is not properly readable.

How can I change that text color to white?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following CSS:

```
input[type=file]
{
    color: white;
}
```

(tested in Safari 5)

Comment: it is working nice with safari.my problem is almost solved with your solution. But what if in case user uses firefox or something else where it comes with white textbox where white fonts won't be able to see

Comment: You could try to set the background colour your CSS: `background: black;` (works in Chrome, I haven't tried other browsers)

Answer (score 1):

First Check out this demo page in safari, it is from second url.......

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/filestyle/demo.html

I think you find enough things from below sites.

- http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html
- http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/filestyle